# How safe is Ecuador today (Summer 2023) for English-speaking tourists?

Tags: safety, ecuador

The crime situation in Ecuador seems to be in flux.  Three months ago, in April 2023, the Ecuadorian President allowed people to bear arms and pepper spray. This was done in response to the growing lawlessness in the country.
(For example, see; Ecuadorian President okays right to bear arms and pepper spray: https://en.mercopress.com/2023/04/03/ecuadorian-president-okays-right-to-bear-arms-and-pepper-spray)

I read that much of the crime is among drug dealers.

How much serious crime is there involving English speaking tourists in the cities of Quito and Guayaquil and in rural areas such as Tena and the surrounding jungle?

Comment: Disagree with the close vote. Safety threats in typical tourist areas can be objectively measured.